# Pass in an array of PaymentDetailsItemType to PayPalAPI

Tags: c#, paypal

I am using the PayPal sandbox in ASP.Net C# 4.0. I added the following web reference:

```
 https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl
```

If i have 1 item (gimme 2 t-shirts please) i can pass it to the PayPal object and complete my transactions with no problems whatsoever:

```
       var item = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsItemType
        {
            Quantity = 2, //etc...etc
        };
         var paymentDetails = new  PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsType();
        paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = new PaymentDetailsItemType[]{item};
```

Now my dilemma is when a customer wants different items (1 t-shirt, 1 pair of pants). Now i need multiple PaymentDetailsItemType objects to pass to the paymentDetails object. I tried this:

```
        //now i have an array of different items 
        var items = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsItemType[3];
        items[0].Description = "T-shirt";
        items[1].Description = "Jeans";
        paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = new PaymentDetailsItemType[]{items};
```

I get this error:

```
       Cannot implicitly convert type 'PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsItemType[]' 
       to 'PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsItemType'
```

I can do this and it compiles:

```
   paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = new PaymentDetailsItemType[]{items[0],items[1]};
```

But when I run it, i get Data type '' mismatch in element 'Quantity' when i call the PayPal service:

```
            PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsType();

        paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsItemType[] { items[0],items[1] };

        reqDetails.PaymentDetails = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsType[] { paymentDetails };

        PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.SetExpressCheckoutReq req = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.SetExpressCheckoutReq()
        {
            SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.SetExpressCheckoutRequestType()
            {
                Version = Version,
                SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = reqDetails
            }
        };

        // query PayPal and get token
         //error occurs here
        PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.SetExpressCheckoutResponseType resp = BuildPayPalWebservice().SetExpressCheckout(req); //this is where the error occurs
```

How do i pass multiple  types to the PayPal API web service so the user can order different items? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you already have an array, so it makes no sense to create a new one just for the sake of assignment into `paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem`:

```
var items = new PayPalAPIHelper.PayPalWS.PaymentDetailsItemType[3];
…
paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = items;  // this is wrong: new PaymentDetailsItemType[]{items};
```

By writing `new PaymentDetailsItemType[]{items}` you create a new array and try to initialize its first item (of type `PaymentDetailsItemType`) with the contents of another array `items` (of type `PaymentDetailsItemType[]` — hence incompatible).

Second, make sure you fill all required properties for *all* items in the array. Most likely, in your example of one t-shirt and one jeans you should do:

```
items[0].Description = "T-shirt";
items[0].Quantity = 1;
items[1].Description = "Jeans";
items[1].Quantity = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but im not sure i understand your answer. If it try to create a new array like this new PaymentDetailsItemType[]{items}, it wont compile like i mentioned in my question. Can you expound a little more and show me how to pass my items array to my paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItems collection? Forgive me , its sunday morning so my mind is still waking up :)

Comment: Have a cup of coffe a do read again the first half of my answer. What you are looking for is: `paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = items;` — just assign the `items` variable (of an array type) into `paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem` property (of the same array type).

Comment: Had my coffe and im good. I implemented your change and i still get the Data type '' mismatch in element 'Quantity' error

Comment: Nevermind....remind me to wake up before i decide to work...I fixed it. Thanks for your help